# Replace Strings into html mail template

Tags: java

I have this HTML template which I would like to send as HTML e-mail:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="background-color: #222533; padding: 20px; font-family: font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.43;>
      Some_text
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

How I can replace for example the name and some String into the e-mail body before I send it?

Comment: Please elaborate, it's not very clear what you are trying to do...

Comment: Have you considerd to use a template engine like [Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

```
String html = "your html tags --- ###SOME_TEXT### ----end of html part";
String htmlToBeSent= "html that will be different to be sent in email";
```

Replace the tag with your html that is to be sent, use string replace function of Java

```
html = html.replace("###SOME_TEXT###",htmlToBeSent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the content of your html, convert it as a `String` and then replace text into this string with the [replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) method:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("path of the html file");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
    content.append(s);
}

String contentAsString = content.toString();
contentAsString = contentAsString.replace("myOldText", "myNewText");
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you need then you can just build your String together with your text.

```
StringBuilder content = 
          new StringBuilder
          ("<html><body style="background-color: #222533; padding: 20px; font-family: font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.43;>");

//you can append any text here.
content.append(" you can put here your text ");

//or you can append a variable
content.append(variableName);

//then finish your html
content.append("</div></body></html>");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the other solution provided, but if you plan to use it in a professional environment, or make it easier in the future to maintains if the mail get more complicated, you should use a template engine, such as velocity. Here is a working example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Velocity/UseVelocitytogenerateHTMLbasedemail.htm